Sitecore Connect to Content Hub Connection 400 Error Authentication
Really new to Sitecore Connect and trying to establish a connection to the sandbox content hub. I created an oauth client setup using keys I specified. I get a 400 bad request message from Connect. I think it at least means it is going to the CH. I see tutorials on how to connect Sitecore to to CH, but not Connect. Any help is greatly appreciated. I did look here, but seems the documentation is missing. https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/configuring-sitecore-connect-for-content-hub.html


Is the user you providing the content hub user or an OAuth client?

Are you specifying the OAuth Client Id and secret created, as per mentioned on the below documentation. https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/developers/cloud-dev/authentication-1286040.html#set-up-oauth-in-sitecore-content-hub.

@DannyPaul It is my user id.

@ckhanna I did. I think my setup is for the oAuth client is correct.

@RReilley as ckhanna says,  you should create an OAuth Client, follow his link on how to configure it.

There are two parts, the OAuth Client and the API key.

There is a call made in the network tab to "test_async.json". Check all these parameters are getting passed..client_id,client_secret,username,password and instance_uri..

I get a 401 Unauthorized. I think that means it is at least trying to connect to the CH.

You can check whether the user you are entering on the Sitecore Connect have permission to create access token. You can check on the same using below Rest Api:
Post Url: {{ContentHub_InstanceUrl}}/oauth/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Request Payload

grant_type: password
username: {{UserName}}
password: {{Password}}
client_id: {{Client_Id}}
client_secret: {{Client_Secret}}


Once the user is able to successfully create access token, you should be able to  connect to Content Hub from Sitecore Connect.
Hope this helps!!!

Thank you! This worked.

Glad to hear that...Thanks @RReilley
